# Infinite scroll in Angular 5, populated by a httpClient request

Tags: json, angular, object, httprequest, infinite-scroll

I would like to implement an infinite scroll populated by a very big json, within Angular 5. The idea is to show only the 5 first entries and then, when a user scroll, it shows the 5 more.

Now, I had a look on this : https://github.com/orizens/ngx-infinite-scroll but the array used for the view only take strings.

I had a look at an example : [Plunker Example of ngx-infinite-scroll](https://plnkr.co/edit/DrEDetYnZkFxR7OWWrxS?p=preview) and what cause the problem is this :

```
  addItems(startIndex, endIndex, _method) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.sum; ++i) {
      this.array[_method]([i, ' ', this.generateWord()].join(''));
    }
  }
```

Where this.generateWord() only generate random strings and _method is push or unshift.

How could I push or concat parts of an object into this so I can still make it work with my *ngFor inside my html template ?

Any idea of a plugin that accept http request object or how to make ngx-infinite-scroll work ?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! I just took a quick look at the library ... and even though the example shows string, you should be able to display any values/objects that you need.

Comment: Hi Deborahk, Thank you for the welcome message and thanks for your time trying to help me with this issue. Please take a look, I have updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I didn't follow "best practices" for the code layout and don't show how to actually get data from a server to populate it ... but I did answer the basic question of how to use an object instead of a string to display.

The result is here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a5ew8f

I just replaced the hard-coded string with entries from a hard-coded array:

```
  addItems(startIndex, endIndex, _method) {
    let movieIndex=0
    for (let i = 0; i < this.sum; ++i) {
      movieIndex++;
      if (movieIndex >= this.movies.length) movieIndex=0;
      this.array[_method](this.movies[movieIndex]);
    }
  }
```

In a *real* application, you would want to go to the server to get 'n' (this.sum) more items each time the addItems method is called.

Comment: Is there an example of this being used with the server?